# Is an online "savings withdrawal" calculator a reasonable model for retirement investment draw downs?

Tags: calculation, retirement-plan, withdrawal

I want to calculate a two-phase retirement, with Phase I being the period prior to filing for Social Security retirement benefits, and Phase II being the post-filing period.

Is it reasonable to use an online "savings withdrawal" calculator for this purpose, plugging in the result from the first calculation in as the starting amount for the second calculation?  What would be a reasonable value to plug into the "rate of return" parameter?

Comment: Yes, it would be.  The value of the ROR parameter depends on where your money is.

Comment: @RonJohn - Thank you.  It's fairly diversified but it leans to the "growth" type.  $430k in TIAA and $80k in Roth IRAs (front-load mutual funds, American Funds to be specific).

Comment: It’s been a long time. Does American Funds still come with a 5% front load and 1%+ per year expense?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica - What do mean about the long time?  // When these funds were acquired they did.  I don't know if they still do.  Is that relevant?  My understanding of financial investments is quite limited.

Comment: @aparente001 - I don't follow funds, per se. I just happened to be engaged in a conversation nearly 20 years ago, and the details were shared with me. I realize that the question was not asking about this, but I still have a bit of PTSD over the details from then.  I am retired, and most of stock investments are within 401(k) accounts with a .016% annual expense. That's .8% between now and the time I plan to meet my maker. Fees add up over time, and spending 1%/yr when my annual withdrawal should be about 4% seems a bit off putting.

Comment: @aparente001 "Is that relevant?" Yes, because such super high costs (they chop **5%** off of every investment and skim double or triple what Vanguard & Fidelity skim off) mean that -- in order to see the same returns as those of us with low-cost brokerages, your investments need to be a lot riskier.

Comment: @RonJohn - Good point -- I'm not making more such purchases nowadays.  But I thought it might help to describe what's in the portfolio.